# hci_send_cmd returns error "operation not permitted" for root user

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, bluez

I've implemented utility for BLE advertise packets sending on Ubuntu 14.04.1. It's work perfectly when I run it from command line with sudo. I want run my utility on system startup therefore I've added it call to /etc/rc.local. After rebooting my utility fails with error **"Error hci_send_cmd: Operation not permitted"** in code:

```
static void set_adv_payload(int dev_num, void * _buf, int _len)
{
    struct hci_filter flt;
    int dd;
    uint16_t ocf;
    uint8_t ogf;
    int err;

    DBG("set_adv_payload buf[0]=%02X, len=%d", *(unsigned char*)_buf, _len);

    dd = hci_open_dev(dev_num);
    if (dd < 0) {
        DBG("Error hci_open_dev %d", dev_num);
        return ;
    }
    hci_filter_clear(&flt);
    hci_filter_set_ptype(HCI_EVENT_PKT, &flt);
    hci_filter_all_events(&flt);

    if (setsockopt(dd, SOL_HCI, HCI_FILTER, &flt, sizeof(flt)) < 0) {
        DBG("Error setsockopt");
        hci_close_dev(dd);
        return;
    }

    ogf = 0x8;
    ocf = 0x8;

    if(hci_send_cmd(dd, ogf, ocf, _len, _buf) < 0)
    {
        DBG("Error hci_send_cmd %s", strerror(errno));
    }

    hci_close_dev(dd);
}
```

I can't understand what's the difference between runing this code from a command line with sudo and running from /etc/rc.local because both runs with root permissions.

```
user@dev-ws12-ubuntu:~$ ps -aux | grep leadv
root       979  0.0  0.0   4352   748 ?        S    17:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/leadv
```

Comment: I have found the workaround for this:
$ sudo crontab -e
...
@rebooth sleep 20 && leadv